# Default PATH variable set with .bash_profile empty

Tags: path, terminal, osx-lion

I remember after a fresh install of os x, when i did a echo $PATH in the terminal, it responded with a blank line. Now after installing some tools over time, the $PATH variable has /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin    value although my .bash_profile is blank. I was wondering where this value is being set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plausible candidates would be `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`; there's also `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d` to look at.  You might also need to look at `$HOME/.profile` and `$HOME/.bashrc`.  There might be some other places that `bash` looks too.

Comment: /etc/paths.d is a read only file and it had the above variables except  "/opt/X11/bin". ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc does not exist on osx. There's only ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: I created `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` for myself; that's my privilege and could be yours too.  `/etc/paths.d` is a directory containing a file `40-XQuartz` which lists `/opt/X11/bin`; `/etc/paths` is a file with the other values in it, one per line.

Comment: On my Mac, ~/.bash_profile does exist, and it is configured (by default, I believe) to look for and execute ~/.bashrc that you may create.
  `test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: In addition to Jonathan Leffler's answer, the `/etc/paths.d` folder should contain specific application related text files whose contents have their related paths inside them. These specific application path-files get added to what is contained in `/etc/paths` when the `$PATH` variable gets generated. Jonathan's system has a `40-XQuartz` path-file in the `/etc/paths.d` folder, and the files in this folder are read in numerical-alphabetic order, so a file called `30-SpecificApplicationName` with a list of paths inside would appear before the `40-XQuartz` path-file when `$PATH` is generated.

Answer (score 5):

As of macOS Catalina, Mac defaults the shell to zsh (Z shell). This type of shell uses `.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`. To check if you are on bash or zsh, run `echo $SHELL`. If the result is `bin/zsh`, you are on zsh. In which case edit your `~/.zprofile` for env variables.